# How does the order between limsup and summation affect the result?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a double-indexed real sequence $\{ x_{n,m}\}$, do we have

$$ \limsup_{n} \sum_m x_{n,m} \leq \sum_m \limsup_{n} \, x_{n,m}$$

$$ \liminf_{n} \sum_m x_{n,m} \geq \sum_m \liminf_{n} \,x_{n,m}?$$

I am not sure about these, and just have some guess based on how sup and sum commute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the xs are nonnegative, the sum of the liminfs is at most the liminf of the sums. This is Fatou's lemma, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma which explains some weaker hypothesis and the corresponding statement for limsups.

Comment: What do we do if the series $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x_{n,m}$ is not convergent? (if the $x_{n,m}$ are not necessary nonnegative, the sequence $\{\sum_{m=0}^Nx_{n,m}\}$ may have no limit at all, even in $\overline{\mathbb R}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where the sequences are nonegative, this is a consequence of the more general [Fatou's Lemma.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)

Comment: Careful (with that axe) Eric... Fatou does not like real valued sequences without some restriction.

Comment: @Didier:  Thanks, you are right.  Although, shouldn't the inequality still be true provided the sequences converge?  Not sure how to prove this though..

Comment: Eric, try x(n,m)=(-1) if m<n and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @Didier:  I don't think both sides converge in that case?

Comment: Eric, right, then x(n,m)=(-2^(m-n)) if m<n and 0 otherwise: lim_n sum_m x(n,m) is lim_n -1+1/2^n = -1 but sum_m lim_n x(n,m) is sum_m 0 = 0.